# Unable to connect to selenium chrome standalone driver

Tags: node.js, selenium, codeceptjs

login --
× "before all" hook: codeceptjs.beforeSuite for "test something" in 6432ms
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

-- FAILURES:

1. login
   "before all" hook: codeceptjs.beforeSuite for "test something":
   Cannot convert undefined or null to object
   at Function.values ()
   at SeleniumStandaloneLauncher.onPrepare (node_modules@wdio\selenium-standalone-service\build\launcher.js:80:22)
   at async C:\Users\bachans\node_modules\codeceptjs\lib\plugin\wdio.js:218:11

FAIL  | 0 passed, 1 failed   // 6s
Run with --verbose flag to see complete NodeJS stacktrace

Comment: Is it a new WebdriverIO setup you have done with selenium-standalone server? What action you have done when you are getting this error?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt comment.
I have gone through many tutorials and this is the one of them please
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZWFFLbMJIQ

Comment: Share code snippets

Comment: below is the codecept.conf.js----
exports.config = {
  tests: './*_test.js',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      url: 'https://www.google.com',
      browser: 'chrome'
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js'
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
  name: 'CodeceptJSWDIO',
  plugins: {
    pauseOnFail: {},
    retryFailedStep: {
      enabled: true
    },
    tryTo: {
      enabled: true
    },
    screenshotOnFail: {
      enabled: true
    }, wdio: {
      enabled: true,
      services: ['selenium-standalone']
    }
  }
}

Comment: @ShivBachan I see issue in the url you are using. It should be prefixed with https following with www
Also you can refer to one of my video https://youtu.be/_0PbQ_UHcyc

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I see an issue with the URL you are using. It should be as shown in the image

Comment: you can vote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: I want to vote it but unfortunately I don't have much reputation...thanks!